# Regarding the use of jquery wild card

Tags: jquery

when i am comparing then i want to use wild card. suppose the target id is `"foolinkbar"`

and this way i am comparing but got no luck. here is the code

```
$("html").click(
              function (e) {
                  if (e.target.is("[id*=link]")  && e.target.id != "HoverSubmenu"
                        && e.target.className != "HoverRoot"
                        && e.target.className != "HoverLI" 
                        && e.target.className != "atag") {
                      $('div#HoverSubmenu').fadeOut();
                  }
              });
```

how to write `e.target.id== "[id*=link]"`. please help me to sort out. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The target is not a jQuery object so you cannot call the `is` function on it.  Wrap the element with `$()`.

**Plain Example**

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    if($(e.target).is("[name*='link']")){
        alert("Found");
    }
});
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/4vCuq/

**Your Code Modified**

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).is("[id*=link]")  && e.target.id != "HoverSubmenu"
        && e.target.className != "HoverRoot"
        && e.target.className != "HoverLI" 
        && e.target.className != "atag") {
            $('div#HoverSubmenu').fadeOut();
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That is a strange mix of JavaScript and jQuery syntax and is also invalid since the [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method cannot be called on an HTML target. It needs to be called on a jQuery object.

The CSS attribute selector `[id*=link]` is perfectly valid.

The jQuery way to do this is:

```
$('html').on('click', '[id*=link]', function() {
    if (this.id != 'HoverSubmenu'
        && this.className != 'HoverRoot'
        && this.className != 'HoverLI' 
        && this.className != 'atag') {
        $('div#HoverSubmenu').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Given the sample HTML

```
<a id="foolinkbar">foolinkbar</a>

<div id="HoverSubmenu">I will fade out when you click foolinkbar but not when other parts of the page are clicked</div>
```

[**See demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yBYUR/1/)